# R boxplot timeseries

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I'm going to explain how my data were built and what exactly I want to show.

- Data from tree diameter where montly measured during 14 months.
- Data were collected in 2 different sites and each of the sites had many
  individuals.

I need to build a "double" timeseries boxplot (by year-month) / site.
Every year-month will have 2 boxes, one from site1 and other from site 2.

I already built it in excel, however negative values were show wrong.

I have no idea on how to build it using R, however with some hints maybe I will be able to build it.

Thanks

Here the dput of my data:

!data DPUT

```
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
13L), .Label = c("01/01/2011", "01/02/2011", "01/03/2011", "01/04/2011", 
"01/05/2011", "01/06/2011", "01/07/2011", "01/08/2011", "01/09/2011", 
"01/10/2010", "01/10/2011", "01/11/2010", "01/11/2011", "01/12/2010"
), class = "factor"), VALUE = structure(c(22L, 46L, 47L, 61L, 
20L, 48L, 38L, 14L, 3L, 37L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 40L, 15L, 26L, 66L, 
34L, 53L, 55L, 59L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 15L, 18L, 15L, 22L, 25L, 38L, 
63L, 28L, 45L, 55L, 44L, 15L, 14L, 20L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 26L, 24L, 
12L, 60L, 46L, 50L, 47L, 26L, 14L, 2L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 25L, 
37L, 18L, 51L, 54L, 52L, 67L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 20L, 25L, 
22L, 22L, 1L, 24L, 47L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 20L, 17L, 15L, 1L, 15L, 
15L, 39L, 17L, 46L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 59L, 60L, 20L, 18L, 2L, 14L, 
2L, 15L, 41L, 23L, 56L, 61L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 38L, 11L, 23L, 15L, 
18L, 14L, 23L, 14L, 1L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 61L, 28L, 53L, 24L, 24L, 17L, 20L, 
15L, 18L, 25L, 65L, 15L, 1L, 44L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 9L, 17L, 
24L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 1L, 53L, 18L, 44L, 58L, 22L, 20L, 23L, 
15L, 37L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 49L, 8L, 49L, 59L, 30L, 31L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 24L, 18L, 26L, 15L, 38L, 4L, 41L, 27L, 31L, 42L, 14L, 
14L, 62L, 17L, 24L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 45L, 60L, 33L, 53L, 
1L, 3L, 68L, 15L, 49L, 7L, 15L, 18L, 38L, 24L, 20L, 24L, 14L, 
15L, 8L, 15L, 26L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 45L, 56L, 61L, 33L, 
38L, 45L, 13L, 18L, 26L, 14L, 22L, 17L, 38L, 17L, 3L, 57L, 64L, 
64L, 51L, 51L, 23L, 17L, 41L, 1L, 3L, 14L, 17L, 14L, 36L, 15L, 
24L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 14L, 1L, 18L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 37L, 15L, 23L, 
22L, 24L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 1L, 15L, 22L, 15L, 
26L, 35L, 9L, 51L, 25L, 25L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 15L, 17L, 25L, 
1L, 10L, 41L, 32L, 45L, 5L, 5L, 53L, 1L, 20L, 17L, 2L, 14L, 15L, 
24L, 4L, 6L, 43L, 24L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 17L, 15L, 
2L, 18L, 15L, 45L, 28L, 22L, 50L, 50L, 15L, 8L, 29L, 22L, 17L, 
24L, 17L), .Label = c("-0,2", "-0,4", "-0,6", "-0,8", "-0,9", 
"-0,9998", "-1", "-1,2", "-2,2", "-2,8", "-3", "-3,2", "-4,4", 
"0", "0,2", "0,3", "0,4", "0,6", "0,7", "0,8", "0,9", "1", "1,2", 
"1,4", "1,6", "1,8", "10", "10,6", "10,8", "11,4", "11,6", "12,6", 
"12,8", "13,6", "14,4", "17.998", "2", "2,2", "2,4", "2,6", "2,8", 
"21,2", "23.998", "3", "3,2", "3,4", "3,6", "3,8", "4", "4,2", 
"4,4", "4,6", "4,8", "5", "5,2", "5,4", "5,6", "5,8", "6,2", 
"6,4", "6,6", "7,4", "7,8", "8", "8,2", "8,6", "8,8", "9,6"), class = "factor"), 
    INDIVIDUAL = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
    17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
    23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 
    24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
    24L), .Label = c("co01", "co02", "co03", "co04", "co05", 
    "co06", "co07", "co08", "co09", "jb01", "jb02", "jb03", "jb04", 
    "jb05", "jb06", "jb07", "jb08", "spvs01", "spvs02", "spvs03", 
    "spvs04", "spvs05", "spvs06", "spvs07"), class = "factor"), 
    SITE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("site1", "site2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DATE", 
"VALUE", "INDIVIDUAL", "SITE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-332L))
```

Comment: @you Hard to use your data as it is. You should replace your html snippets but just a `dput` of your data. Then what have you tried to plot your boxplots?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you meant by "dput" my data.
However, I already edited the post with the return of dput(data)

Comment: can you explain why you have two numbers in the value field? tree diameter?

Comment: You mean 2 numbers beacause of the "," ?
It is a float number wich represents the monthly variation of the tree individual diameter.

Answer (score 3):

You should format your data before plotting:

```
dat$DATE <- as.Date(dat$DATE,"%d/%m/%Y")
dat$VALUE <- as.numeric(gsub(',','.',dat$VALUE))
```

Then using `ggplot2` for example, you can do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=format(dat$DATE,'%y %b'),y=VALUE,fill=SITE))
```

[image]

### EDIT :

To get better idea how your data varies across individuals you can plot a `heatmap` using `geom_tile`:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=months(DATE),y=INDIVIDUAL,fill=VALUE)) +
  facet_grid(SITE~.,scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: Great!
It's almost what I need.

However, it display only 12 months. I already have 14 (2 differente years). Months appears to be in alphabetical order, but it should be chronological.

Comment: @user1424495 I edit my plot to get 14 periods. You need just now to  set pretty x lables...